# Will using a shared_ptr on class instance members clean up correctly when the owning object drops out of scope?

Tags: c++

will using a shared_ptr on class instance members clean up the new'ed objects correctly when the owning "parent" drops out of scope? Like in the example below?

Code example below - so when the Family instance goes out of scope will it clean up/delete the people objects linked to in the map?

If so how can i confirm this? Are there tools i can use to show before and after - after showing no person object - and if i put the normal pointers back i should still see the person objects - thanks

```
class Family
{
private:
    //std::map<int ,Person*> _people;
    std::map<int ,std::tr1::shared_ptr<Person>> _people;

public:
    void AddPerson(int age)
    {
        //_people[age] = new Person(age);
        _people[age] = std::tr1::shared_ptr<Person>( new Person(age));
    }
};

    class Person
    {
    private:
        int _age;
    public: 
        Person(int age)
        {
            _age= age;
        }
        int GetName(){return _age;}
    };
```

Comment: It would be nice if the down votes where motivated to let @CodingQuant know why you don't like his question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through it: `Family` goes out of scope, `_people` is destroyed, the `map` destructor removes all it's elements, which means that for each element, the destructor is called. All `shared_ptrS` in the map decrement their reference count. If the reference count is now 0, the objects are destroyed. Although I don't see why you would store a pointer (smart or not) in your example, I guess you have your reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `shared_ptr` is a reference counting smart pointer who takes ownership of the new object.

When a Family is destructed its members including the _people map will be deleted. When a map is deleted it's contents are deleted.

If _people was just a map containing `Person *` the the destructor of Family would have to delete each Person (if not known by somebody else).

Using `shared_ptr` seems good for this example. You could for example return `shared_ptr` of the son of one family and make him the father of another family.

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<Person> getSon(){
      return someOne... ;
}
```

For the smart pointer stuff to work you need to return by value so that the copy constructor is called. Then you can safely delete one family without corrupting another.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That will behave as you expect and as it should. `std::tr1::shared_ptr` can be used in STL structures; on the other hand the old `auto_ptr` cannot.

Comment: Don't even mention `auto_ptr`. No one wants to remember it and is deprecated.

Comment: I think the only reason people ask this question is that they have heard for years that smart pointer (read `auto_ptr`) and STL do not mix.

Answer (score 0):

The map member _people will be cleaned but not the Person shared pointers, unless some of them reach refcount 0